# Send message with sockets on unix - weird behaviour

Tags: c, sockets, unix, hash, client-server

I'm learning unix sockets, and I decided to write a simple client/server program for local communication.
It simply works as follows: the server creates a socket and starts listening until a client connects, receives the message and simply sends it back to the client; on the other side, the clients connects to the socket, sends a string message, receives the server response and terminates.

I successfully implemented such program. For **testing** purposes (I know it doesn't make sense, it's just a test), I wanted to add to the bottom of the message an hash of the message itselfs. I used the OpenSSL implementation of the SHA256 function, modifying the behaviour as follows:

- the server creates a socket and starts listening;
- the client connects to the socket, asks for a string to send, computes the hash of that string, concatenates it to the original message (using a pipe "|" as separator) and sends the message to the server;
- the server splits the message into plain text and hash, computes the hash of the plain part and checks it with the received hash

  - if they match, it adds something to the plain message
  - if they don't, it overwrites the original plain message
  - ...then it computes the hash of the new message, and sends it to the client
- the client receives the message and checks the hash in the same way

Now, the problem is that I use **exactly the same functions** for computing and verifying the hash, but on the server side I get an hash mismatch, while on the client side everything works as expected.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

Server output:

```
Socket created
Bind done
Waiting for incoming connections...
Connection accepted
Message received
Message: hello
Hash not corresponding
Message sent
```

Client output:

```
Socket created
Connected
Enter message to send: hello
Message sent
Message received
Hashes match
Server reply: Hash mismatch
```

Here is the server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int simpleSHA256(void *input, unsigned long length, unsigned char *md) {
    SHA256_CTX context;
    if(!SHA256_Init(&context))
        return 0;

    if(!SHA256_Update(&context, (unsigned char*)input, length))
        return 0;

    if(!SHA256_Final(md, &context))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int socket_desc, client_sock, c;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char client_message[1000], client_plain_message[1000], server_message[1000], *received_client_message_hash;

    // Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1) {
        printf("Could not create socket\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket created\n");

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);

    // Bind
    if (bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("Bind failed. Error");
        close(socket_desc); close(client_sock); return 1;
    }
    printf("Bind done\n");

    // Start listening
    listen(socket_desc, 3);
    printf("Waiting for incoming connections...\n");

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    // Accept connection
    if ((client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) < 0) {
        perror("Accept failed");
        close(socket_desc); close(client_sock); return 1;
    }
    printf("Connection accepted\n");

    // Receive message from client
    if (recv(client_sock, client_message, 1000, 0) < 0 ) {
        perror("Receive failed");
        close(socket_desc); close(client_sock); return 1;
    }
    printf("Message received\n");

    strcpy(client_plain_message, client_message);
    strtok_r(client_plain_message, "|", &received_client_message_hash);

    // Verify hash
    unsigned char computed_client_message_hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    if(!simpleSHA256(client_plain_message, strlen(client_plain_message), computed_client_message_hash)) {
        printf("Error computing hash\n");
        close(socket_desc); close(client_sock); return 1;
    }

    printf("Message: %s\n", client_plain_message);

    if (!strcmp(computed_client_message_hash, received_client_message_hash)) {
        printf("Hash not corresponding\n");

        strcpy(server_message, "Hash mismatch");
    } else {
        printf("Hashes match\n");

        strcpy(server_message, client_plain_message);
        strcat(server_message, "_added_text_");
    }

    // Compute new hash
    unsigned char message_hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    if(!simpleSHA256(client_plain_message, strlen(client_plain_message), message_hash)) {
        printf("Error computing hash\n");
        close(socket_desc); close(client_sock); return 1;
    }

    // Concatenate new hash with response
    strcat(server_message, "|");
    strcat(server_message, message_hash);

    // Ansers to client
    if (write(client_sock, server_message, strlen(server_message)) < 0) {
        perror("Write failed");
        close(socket_desc); close(client_sock); return 1;
    }

    printf("Message sent\n");

    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int simpleSHA256(void *input, unsigned long length, unsigned char *md) {
    SHA256_CTX context;
    if(!SHA256_Init(&context))
        return 0;

    if(!SHA256_Update(&context, (unsigned char*)input, length))
        return 0;

    if(!SHA256_Final(md, &context))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char client_message[1000], server_reply[1000], server_message[1000], *received_server_message_hash;

    // Create socket
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        printf("Could not create socket\n");
        close(sock); return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket created\n");

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); // destination ip
    server.sin_port = htons(8888); // destination port

    // Connect to server
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("Connect failed. Error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Connected\n");

    printf("Enter message to send: ");
    scanf("%s", client_message);

    // Compute hash
    unsigned char client_message_hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    if(!SHA256(client_message, strlen(client_message), client_message_hash)) {
        printf("Error computing hash\n");
        close(sock); return 1;
    }

    // Concatenate hash with message
    strcat(client_message, "|");
    strcat(client_message, client_message_hash);

    // Send message
    if (write(sock, client_message, strlen(client_message)) < 0) {
        printf("Write failed\n");
        close(sock); return 1;
    }

    printf("Message sent\n");

    // Receive response
    if (recv(sock, server_reply, 1000, 0) < 0) {
        printf("Receive failed\n");
        close(sock); return 1;
    }
    printf("Message received\n");

    strcpy(server_message, server_reply);
    strtok_r(server_message, "|", &received_server_message_hash);

    // Verify hash
    unsigned char computed_server_message_hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    if(!simpleSHA256(server_message, strlen(server_message), computed_server_message_hash)) {
        printf("Error computing hash\n");
        close(sock); return 1;
    }

    // Check if hashes match
    if (!strcmp(computed_server_message_hash, received_server_message_hash)) {
        printf("Hash not corresponding\n");
        close(sock); return 1;
    }
    printf("Hashes match\n");

    printf("Server reply: %s\n", server_message);

    // Close connection
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not nice `int c; ... accept(..., (socklen_t*)&c)`

Comment: They say `strlen()` and networking code do not go together ... ;-)

Comment: Good point, thank you. I resolved my particular problem by replacing `strlen()` with a constant value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem by replacing `strlen()` with a constant value, as pointed out by alk.

Note: the code below was just a test, and it's not meant to be bug free or fully working for any purpose. I'm posting it as a solution limited to the problem I was experiencing.

Updated client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 10000

int simpleSHA256(void *input, unsigned long length, unsigned char *md) {
    SHA256_CTX context;
    if(!SHA256_Init(&context))
        return 0;

    if(!SHA256_Update(&context, (unsigned char*)input, length))
        return 0;

    if(!SHA256_Final(md, &context))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char client_message[MAX_LENGTH], server_reply[MAX_LENGTH], server_message[MAX_LENGTH], *received_server_message_hash;

    // Create socket
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        printf("Could not create socket\n");
        close(sock); return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket created\n");

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); // destination ip
    server.sin_port = htons(8888); // destination port

    // Connect to server
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("Connect failed. Error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Connected\n");

    printf("Enter message to send: ");
    scanf("%s", client_message);

    // Compute hash
    unsigned char client_message_hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    if(!SHA256(client_message, MAX_LENGTH, client_message_hash)) {
        printf("Error computing hash\n");
        close(sock); return 1;
    }

    // Concatenate hash with message
    strcat(client_message, "|");
    strcat(client_message, client_message_hash);

    // Send message
    if (write(sock, client_message, MAX_LENGTH) <= 0) {
        printf("Write failed\n");
        close(sock); return 1;
    }

    printf("Message sent\n");

    // Receive response
    if (recv(sock, server_reply, MAX_LENGTH, 0) <= 0) {
        perror("Receive failed");
        close(sock); return 1;
    }
    printf("Message received\n");

    strcpy(server_message, server_reply);
    strtok_r(server_message, "|", &received_server_message_hash);

    // Verify hash
    unsigned char computed_server_message_hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    if(!simpleSHA256(server_message, MAX_LENGTH, computed_server_message_hash)) {
        printf("Error computing hash\n");
        close(sock); return 1;
    }

    // Check if hashes match
    if (!strcmp(computed_server_message_hash, received_server_message_hash)) {
        printf("Hash not corresponding\n");
        close(sock); return 1;
    }
    printf("Hashes match\n");

    printf("Server reply: %s\n", server_message);

    // Close connection
    fflush(stdout);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Updated server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 10000

int simpleSHA256(void *input, unsigned long length, unsigned char *md) {
    SHA256_CTX context;
    if(!SHA256_Init(&context))
        return 0;

    if(!SHA256_Update(&context, (unsigned char*)input, length))
        return 0;

    if(!SHA256_Final(md, &context))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int socket_desc, client_sock, c;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char client_message[MAX_LENGTH], client_plain_message[MAX_LENGTH], server_message[MAX_LENGTH], *received_client_message_hash;

    // Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1) {
        printf("Could not create socket\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket created\n");

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // accetto da qualsiasi indirizzo
    server.sin_port = htons(8888); // porta di ascolto

    // Bind
    if (bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("Bind failed. Error");
        close(socket_desc); close(client_sock); return 1;
    }
    printf("Bind done\n");

    // Start listening
    listen(socket_desc, 3);
    printf("Waiting for incoming connections...\n");

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    // Accept connection
    if ((client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) < 0) {
        perror("Accept failed");
        close(socket_desc); close(client_sock); return 1;
    }
    printf("Connection accepted\n");

    // Receive message from client
    if (recv(client_sock, client_message, MAX_LENGTH, 0) <= 0 ) {
        perror("Receive failed");
        close(socket_desc); close(client_sock); return 1;
    }
    printf("Message received\n");

    strcpy(client_plain_message, client_message);
    strtok_r(client_plain_message, "|", &received_client_message_hash);

    printf("%i\n", strlen(client_plain_message));

    // Verify hash
    unsigned char computed_client_message_hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    if(!simpleSHA256(client_plain_message, MAX_LENGTH, computed_client_message_hash)) {
        printf("Error computing hash\n");
        close(socket_desc); close(client_sock); return 1;
    }

    printf("Message: %s\n", client_plain_message);

    if (!strcmp(computed_client_message_hash, received_client_message_hash)) {
        printf("Hash not corresponding\n");

        strcpy(server_message, "Hash mismatch");
    } else {
        printf("Hashes match\n");

        strcpy(server_message, client_plain_message);
        strcat(server_message, "_added_text_");
    }

    // Compute new hash
    unsigned char message_hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    if(!simpleSHA256(client_plain_message, MAX_LENGTH, message_hash)) {
        printf("Error computing hash\n");
        close(socket_desc); close(client_sock); return 1;
    }

    // Concatenate new hash with response
    strcat(server_message, "|");
    strcat(server_message, message_hash);

    // Ansers to client
    if (write(client_sock, server_message, MAX_LENGTH) <= 0) {
        perror("Write failed");
        close(socket_desc); close(client_sock); return 1;
    }

    printf("Message sent\n");

    fflush(stdout);
    close(socket_desc);
    close(client_sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By using `strcpy()` and ignoring the actual count returned by `recv()`, you are still subscribing to the same fallacy that makes `strlen()` incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You are

- ignoring the length returned by `recv()`
- assuming that a single read is enough to receive an entire message
- assuming the message is null-terminated.

Examine your assumptions.

Comment: I found a solution limited to the small test I was doing, but your tips are precious. Thanks.